# dropdown options, change the month with choice

Tags: java, date

I have dropdown option list that has numbers through 1-12 representing months. I would like to be able to change the date according to this choice in StudentWorkDayVisualizationController.java. So I want int month to take the selected number value from the dropdown list (if user selects 4 the month becomes 4 and the date is changed according to that). Or if there is better way to do this, please I'm all ears. 
If nothing is selected the program returns previous month from current month. I hope my question was clear enough (I'm sorry if my english is bad or weird, it is not my native language).

http://pastebin.com/L4qfQ46L

```
public class StudentWorkDayVisualizationController {
int month = 0;

@Autowired
private VisualizationService visualizationService;

@ModelAttribute
public void addGraphDatesToModel(ModelMap modelMap) {
    if (month != 0) {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTime startDate = dt.withMonthOfYear(month).withDayOfMonth(1);
        modelMap.addAttribute("startDate", startDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("endDate", startDate.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1));
    }
    else {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime().minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
        modelMap.addAttribute("startDate", startDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("endDate", startDate.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1));
    } 
}
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public String getView() {
    return "visualizationdemo";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "data", method = GET, params = "content=json")
@ResponseBody
public VisualizationJSON getData(ModelMap modelMap) {
    return visualizationService.getVisualizationForStudentWorkDaysDivision(
        (DateTime) modelMap.get("startDate"), (DateTime) modelMap.get("endDate"));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exact solution but I think you have not handeled well, event listeners. Look out event listener part. In Event Listner section there you have to provide your code in side

if(onchange){
 if(itemSelected){
    //your desired code

}
}